# 'HttpContextAccessor' does not contain a definition for 'Session'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

in my view

```
@if(Model.Creator.UserId == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor.Session["UserId"])
    {
        <a href="/events/@Model.EventId/edit" class="btn btn-success no-float inline">Edit</a>
        <form method="post" asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="home" asp-route-id="@Model.EventId" class="inline">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
        </form>
    }
```

In my controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
...    
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", UserInDb.UserId);
```

The error message is under Session in the View IF statement

Comment: You don’t need to use the `HttpContextAccessor` within Razor views. You can just access the `HttpContext` property directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject HttpContext to Razor View with following code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

...

@if(Model.Creator.UserId == Context.Session["UserId"])
    {
        <a href="/events/@Model.EventId/edit" class="btn btn-success no-float inline">Edit</a>
        <form method="post" asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="home" asp-route-id="@Model.EventId" class="inline">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
        </form>
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this led me to figure out how to get it to work in this project!

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler says, [that class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontextaccessor) has nothing called `Session`. The only Property around is `HttpContext`.

The type of `HttpContext` in turn does have a Session Property. And that properties type has a indexer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.session

So what you wanted was probaly:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session["UserId"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to access Session with the following in the View

```
@if(Model.Creator.UserId == Context.Session.GetInt32("UserId"))
{
    <a href="/events/@Model.EventId/edit" class="btn btn-success no-float inline">Edit</a>
    <form method="post" asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="home" asp-route-id="@Model.EventId" class="inline">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
    </form>
}
```